# In Android, how to update GridView cell element control when selected?

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am trying to implement a GridView in Android to display a list of Products as mentioned in below image:
[image]

With Custom Button and Grid List I am implemented this.

I want to know, how can I make this Product Button Red when I select it. Or in other words, I want to get the selected cell item object and change the background color to red, TextViews text color to white. Plus, at the same time, I want to make all remaining cell items to default white background and text color to purple.

I am new to android, any help would be great support. Thanks in advance. Here is my code:

GridView in Fragment

```
<GridView
android:id="@+id/grid_Products"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:numColumns="3"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp />
```

In ProductFragment class in onCreateView() method, I am binding the productModels to gridView

```
List<ProductModel> productModels;
GridView gdGridView=(GridView)(view.findViewById(R.id.grid_Products));
adapter = new ProductButtonAdaptor(view.getContext(), productModels);
gdGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

product_button.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_product_red"
    android:id="@+id/pnl_ProudctButton"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_ProductName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:textColor="@color/purple"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_ProductCurrency"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="QAR"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/purple"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/lbl_ProductSeparator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@color/purple" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_ProductCategory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="International"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/purple"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ProductButtonAdpater class:

```
public class ProductButtonAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<ProductModel> implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
{
private Context context;
private final List<ProductModel> productModels;
private int selected = -1;
public ProductButtonAdaptor(Context context, List<ProductModel> productValues)
{
    super(context, R.layout.button_product, productValues);
    this.context = context;
    this.productModels = productValues;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null)
    {

        gridView = new View(context);

        // get layout from button_product.xml
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_product, null);

        // set value into textview
        TextView lbl_ProductName = (TextView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_ProductName);
        TextView lbl_ProductCurrency = (TextView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_ProductCurrency);
        TextView lbl_ProductCategory = (TextView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_ProductCategory);
        lbl_ProductName.setText(productModels.get(position).getCode());
        lbl_ProductCurrency.setText(productModels.get(position).getCurrency());
        lbl_ProductCategory.setText(productModels.get(position).getCategoryName());

    }
    else
    {
        gridView = (View)convertView;
    }

    if (selected == position)
    {
        TextView lbl_ProductName = (TextView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_ProductName);
        TextView lbl_ProductCurrency = (TextView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_ProductCurrency);
        TextView lbl_ProductCategory = (TextView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_ProductCategory);
        View lbl_ProductSeperator = (View)gridView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_ProductSeparator);
        LinearLayout pnl_ProductButton = (LinearLayout)gridView.findViewById(R.id.pnl_ProudctButton);

        lbl_ProductName.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.vodafone_white));
        lbl_ProductCurrency.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.vodafone_white));
        lbl_ProductCategory.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.vodafone_white));
        lbl_ProductSeperator.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.vodafone_white));
        pnl_ProductButton.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.btn_product_red, null));

    }
    else
    {
        //setup the other cells
        TextView lbl_ProductName = (TextView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_ProductName);
        TextView lbl_ProductCurrency = (TextView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_ProductCurrency);
        TextView lbl_ProductCategory = (TextView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_ProductCategory);
        View lbl_ProductSeperator = (View)gridView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_ProductSeparator);
        LinearLayout pnl_ProductButton = (LinearLayout)gridView.findViewById(R.id.pnl_ProudctButton);

        lbl_ProductName.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.vodafone_purple));
        lbl_ProductCurrency.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.vodafone_purple));
        lbl_ProductCategory.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.vodafone_purple));
        lbl_ProductSeperator.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.vodafone_purple));
        pnl_ProductButton.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.btn_product_white, null));
    }

    return gridView;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return productModels.size();
}

@Override
public ProductModel getItem(int position)
{
    return productModels.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    selected = position;

    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //adapter.notifyDataChanged();

    //parent.invalidate();
    //view.invalidate();
}
}
```

this is the updated code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do it programatically (not styles).

So,

You have to declare a `int selected;` variable which stores index of a selected cell (or -1 if none is selected). Then, you have to implement `onClickListener` on each cell and change `selected` value when any element is tapped and redraw all data grid cells using `notify...` method.

After that, do not forget to change the setup block of colors and other parameters of each sell in the correspond method of the adapter.

inside `onCreate()` method:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(adapter);
```

your class:

```
public class ProductButtonAdaptor extends BaseAdapter implemets onItemClickListener {
private Context context;
private final ProductModel[] productModels;
private int selected = -1;
public ProductButtonAdaptor(Context context, ProductModel[] productValues) {
    this.context = context;
    this.productModels = productValues;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = new View(context);

        // get layout from button_product.xml
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_product, null);

        // set value into textview
        TextView lbl_ProductName = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_ProductName);
        TextView lbl_ProductCurrency = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_ProductCurrency);
        TextView lbl_ProductCategory = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_ProductCategory);
        lbl_ProductName.setText(productModels[position].Name);
        lbl_ProductCurrency.setText(productModels[position].Currency);
        lbl_ProductCategory.setText(productModels[position].CategoryName);

    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    if (selected == position) {
    //setup selected cell
    //for example
    gridView.setBackgroundColor(Color.red);
    } else {
    //setup the other cells
    gridView.setBackgroundColor(Color.white);
    }

    return gridView;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return productModels.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return productModels[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}


 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
    selected = position;

    adapter.notifyDataChanged();
```

//you can pass the grid as a paramater of constructor if you need it
        grid.invalidateViews();

```
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know if it is possible through style. If you can share with me some Style accomplishing this color change feature would be a great help.

Comment: post your adapter class . i will try

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. But I didn't get the meaning of your last comment in code regarding grid.InvalidateViews(). Also, adaptor.notifyDataChanged() was not available, so I changed it to this.notifyDataSetChanged();. Does it impact in any way? I don't know real meaning, why we use this line of code.

Comment: From time to time some users say that notify... doesn't update grid. In order to force redraw i would suggest to use invalidateviews too. No more.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the code. All gridview items are not binding. Also, on scrolling the gridview all the cell contents are getting jumbled up. Can you please help me?

Comment: could you provide more info? screenshots, etc.

Comment: please check this image link ....  https://www.dropbox.com/s/iri0slapodb7c75/gridview_android.png?dl=0

Comment: please check this link dropbox.com/s/iri0slapodb7c75/gridview_android.png?dl=0

Comment: @RobinPurbia , so, this is the other question.let me see.

Comment: @RobinPurbia btw i would suggest to create a new question instead of this comment. more programmers will see it